# select element in selenium using partial xcode or partial css selector

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to select a certain element in a webpage in selenium. I know that the element's name looks like person_xxxxx with xxxx being random numbers. I would like to know if it is possible to select this element using xpath or css selector. So far I have tried:

```
cartes_profils=liste_profils_shadow.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"person_")]')
```

which is deprecated and doesn't work

```
cartes_profils=liste_profils_shadow.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='input[id^="#person_"]')
```

which runs but doesn't select the desired elements

```
cartes_profils=liste_profils_shadow.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value=("//*[contains(@id, 'person_')]"))
```

which returns an "invalid selector" error

PS: I know that there are similar topics already answered but they are all a million years old and the solutions do not work for me

Comment: Could you attach the webpage to try

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using `starts-with` for xpath. Also, yes you are right

`find_elements_by_***` is `deprecated` in `selenium 4`. You should use `find_element(By.XPATH, "")`

so your effective xpath would be:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'person_')]
```

use it like

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'person_')]")
```

and equivalent `CSS` would be: (you are fairly close here)

```
input[id^="person_"]
```

use it like

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^="person_"]")
```

My recommendation would be explicit waits:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'person_')]")))
```

You'll have to import these for explicit waits:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you've suggested to me is exactly the same as the one I wrote in my post and, as I've said, it does not work. The xpath you've specified returns an "invalid locator" error and the css selector you have sugested does not return anything.

Comment: Xpath is not same, you are using contains method which works far differently from starts-with method, also you are using # in css which is wrong, also you are not using explicit waits. Now what's the error do you see with my code, it's a find element method so it got to return a fault I'm case if it does not find the web element.

Comment: Also the deprecated message must have gone, so this answer is still helpful.